# UFT doesn't click a WebCheckBox of a pop-up

Tags: web, checkbox, vbscript, hp-uft, gui-testing

I'm using UFT 15 to automatize some Web GUI Tests using VB Script. I have to click on a WebCheckBox of a pop up but it doesn't work because when I used Record to click on the WebCheckBox, UFT pasted that line:

```
Browser("A").Window("B").WinObject("Internet Explorer_Server").Click
```

I understood that `WinObject("Internet Explorer_Server")` is a generic object.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your browser isn't correctly recognized by UFT, the object hierarchy should be something like: `Browser("A").Page("B").WebElement("C").Click` (where `WebElement` could be quite a few things like `Link`, `WebButton` etc.).

Check if UFT's agent is enabled in your browser (in this case IE).
During the first launch of IE you should have seen a toolbar like this:

[image: Toolbar screenshot]

If you didn't click `Enable` then, you should go to the "Gear icon" -> Manage Add-ons menu and enable the UFT addon:

[image: Manage addon window]